# Can a method return a different return type besides the one specified?

Tags: objective-c

Lets say I have a Deck class which is based on NSObject. 
We also have PlayingCardDeck which is based on the Deck class.

How is the method bellow legal ?

```
 -(Deck *) createDeck
 {

     return [[PlayingCardDeck alloc]init];
 }
```

Comment: Yes if PlayingCardDeck derives from Deck. This is generally useful when you have multiple subclasses.

Comment: Certainly it's legal to return a subclass of the declared return type -- a subclass can always be substituted for its superclass.  And in Objective-C there's nothing (other than maybe a warning message) to really prevent a method from returning, say, an NSString from a method that is declared to return an NSNumber.

Comment: Consider making this a class method and renaming it to be consistent with Cocoa coding guidelines. The resulting signature would be `+ (Deck *)deck` and you would it invoke it like so: `Deck *myDeck = [Deck deck];`

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you coded the object inheritance correctly: yes, it is legal because your PlayingCardDeck is indeed a Deck.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a method can return a different type, as long as it is compatible with the one specified.

> We have `PlayingCardDeck` which is based on the `Deck` class.

Then it is perfectly OK to return an instance of  `PlayingCardDeck`, because it is a `Deck`.

This technique is very important and popular in OOP. It lets you hide the implementation, and expose the interface. For example, you could make several implementations of `Deck`, but let your users know of only the top-level `Deck` class. This gives you flexibility in choosing an implementation without breaking your users' code.

Cocoa framework also uses this concept a lot. For example, some methods of `NSString` declared with the return type of `NSString` actually return a subclass of `NSString`. Since user code does not need to know about the subclass, they can conveniently write `NSString`, and program to its interface.